# How to list Ansible managed files in a file on the managed host?

Tags: ansible

My problem is that administrators like to configure the system directly, and don't want their changes to be overwritten by Ansible.

We only have a very small number of servers running different services used by different administrators and would like to use Ansible to manage just the common settings (OpenSSH, Accounts, DNS-slaves, Backup, etc.), since the rest of the services are easier managed directly on the server. Also not all administrators should need to learn Ansible.

One way I thought of was to insert headers like "This file is managed by Ansible", but that only works with text files. Another way would be to add a empty file into directory like "`/etc/ssh/sshd_config.ansible_managed`", but there are software pieces that use `run-parts` or similar, and might get confused about such files. So the only option I see would be to add a list of managed files to a prominent location on the managed host.

I could not find something about this in the Ansible documentation.

Comment: Most of the configuration files are text-based hence you should be able to insert comments using ansible.

Comment: ... and this is exactly what the [`ansible_managed` variable is made for in the template module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html)

Comment: Well most is not all. Also some of the configuration is done through symlinks, like timezone and enabled services. Headers is a nice additional way to signify that certain files are managed, but not a way that works in all cases. A file containing a list of managed files, or even implemented changes on the server itself would work in all cases. Maybe this is implementable in a callback plugin?

Answer (score 0):

you could add the following:

```
{{ ansible_managed | comment }}
```

This will put a # on every line.